# Quitar URL de la ventana window.open

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, edge

estoy trabajando con Edge, ¿hay alguna forma de quitar la URL de una ventana popup que se abre con window.open? No me interesa enmascarla. Me interesa quitar toda esa parte para tener más espacio en la ventana.

Algo tipo:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy haciendo pruebas aquí pero no lo consigo. He visto que hay varios "atributos" que se le puede poner "menubar=no, location=no, resizable=yes, etc" pero no se si hay alguno para ocultar esa parte de la ventana.
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_win_open2

Comment: Siento decirte que la mayoría de navegadores ya no implementan esa funcionalidad para evitar problemas de seguridad como el [browser spoofing](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_spoofing) o suplantación de navegador. Es una decisión magnífica y, como usuario, deberías agradecerla.

Comment: Tal y como te comenta @franmost la mayoría de navegadores no implementan esa funcionalidad aunque siga en la [definición de los atributos de `window` en HTML5](https://www.w3.org/html/wg/spec/browsers.html#barprop). Es decir, que `window.locationbar` debería valer siempre `true` a no ser que la página esté a pantalla completa, el navegador esté en modo quiosco o en algún modo especial especificado de manera explícita en el navegador (es decir, un modo que no ha sido provocado por código JavaScript). Incluso en esos casos es posible que la implementación del navegador siga devolviendo `true`.